# UI does not get updated after updating property in DelegateCommand method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a window (opened from the main window ViewModel) that contains a ListView and a button. The content of this ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FoundElements}" Grid.Row="2" />
```

and the button triggers a command

```
<Button Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" Margin="10 0 0 0">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
     </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

In the ViewModel I have the bound DelegateCommand and the Property.

```
private ObservableCollection<String> _foundElements;

public ObservableCollection<string> FoundElements
{
     get { return _foundElements; }
     set { _foundElements= value; OnPropertyChanged("FoundElements"); }
}

ICommand _searchCommand;

public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get { return _searchCommand; }
    set { _searchCommand = value; }
}
```

In the constructor:

```
this.SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => SearchMethod());
```

If I modify the property in the constructor, the window is shown with the modified property (i.e. there are element in the list) but if I modify the property in the DelegateCommand method, after pressing the button, it does not (I checked and I enter in the Method).

```
this.FoundElements = new ObservableCollection<String>() { "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a" };
```

The window is created in the main window ViewModel

```
SubWindow w = new SubWindow();
w.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
w.Show();
```

And in the SubWindow code-behind I assign the DataContext

```
public SubWindow()
{
    this.DataContext = new SubWindowViewModel();

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

This is OnPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Switching the DataContext assignment and the InitialiseComponent() I get this error in the console:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=FoundElements; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

Creating the window/ updating the property inside a Dispatcher, like:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // code
}));
```

does not have any effect.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it should work. INPC is obviously not working for some reason. . What's does OnPropertyChanged() look like?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I modified the question.

Comment: Can you show the `SearchMethod()` function that is called by your delegate command?

Comment: It just does:

private void SearchMethod()
{
this.FoundElements = new ObservableCollection<String>() { "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a" };
}

Comment: put a messagebox to see if ur method is reachable or not ?

Comment: I put a breakpoint and it enters the method.

Comment: make your itemssource binding mode= twoway.

Comment: It shouldn't need to be TwoWay, but I tried and the is no change...

Comment: put your datacontext below InitializeComponent.

Comment: It's what I meant when I said:

Switching the DataContext assignment and the InitialiseComponent() I get this error in the console:

System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=FoundElements; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: when everything is alright, then it should work. can u upload at dropbox.com.

Comment: No... sorry, but It's a big project and what I presented here is only a little part of it.

Comment: Also there are other windows opened in the same way that do comparable  stuff, organised in a similar way and they work...

Comment: Are you DEFINITELY calling `OnPropertyChanged()` with "FoundElements"? ie the property name matches properly? You're sure there's no typo in your real code?

Comment: Nope... copied/ pasted it to be sure. What drives me nuts is that no property update works. I tried to bind the content of the button, creating a string property called Name and binding it to the content. In the Method called by the command I tried to change the content of the button and it does not. Of course the assignation in the constructor instead works...

Comment: What is the relationship between the `new SubWindowViewModel()` that you create in the Subwindow constructor and the view model in which you called `SearchMethod()`? It isn't even clear if the `FoundElements` property is in SubWindowViewModel or in a "main" view model.

Comment: They are the same. I checked if for some reason there was a double initialisation.

Comment: Yes, and the properties I initialise here are shown. The problem is when I try to modify them in the method called by the DelegateCommand.

Comment: FoundElements is in the SubWindowViewModel

Comment: This may or may not be useful, but I copy/pasted the code above into a minimal project and it works for me, so the problem is likely outside the code you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use VisualStudio 2010 with .Net 4...........

Comment: I have 2015 but it works when I set it to C# 4.0 and .NET 4

Comment: Ok, I am an asshole: forgot to make the ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged -.- it was some time I didn't touch C# code. Embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel had to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. As easy as this. Dammit, I lost an afternoon on this.